# Configuring the database properties from outside of intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I want to ask as currently I have my database properties like username and password inside the persistence layer in the intellij. But I want to place it somewhere outside so if  someone wants to change the password or any configuration inside database he should not have to dig inside my current structure. Now my structure is  persistence then main then resources and then dbconfig properties so is there any way I can do it.

Comment: what means inside intellij? Do you use spring boots application properties file for defining datasource?

Comment: yes I use spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file `app.properties` in your `resources` folder with all database information you need:

```
# Datasource details
testapp.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
testapp.db.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test
testapp.db.username = username
testapp.db.password = password
```

Then you can refer to it in your Java code as:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("testapp.db.driver"));
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("testapp.db.url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("testapp.db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("testapp.db.password"));
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi DimaSan, thank you for your suggestion ..I was wondering shall I choose resource bundle for this app.properties then 2 files are generated for this app.properties in which one I should put my db details ?

Comment: Hi @siya, yes you can do it using ResourceBundle as well, check for the [good example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file-with-a-resource-bundle.html). But personally for me this scenario is clearer and easier to use.